# does scriptaculous still have Javascript hacking vulnerability?

Tags: scriptaculous

Scriptaculous is listed with the Javascript Hacking vulnerability in the following site: 
[http://nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2007-2384]

Does any know if this has been resolved since the article was posted in 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the vulnerability of Scriptaculous was due to Prototype js 1.6.
https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2007-2383
If u want to use scriptaculous without vulnerability u have to replace the prototype js file in the scriptaculos with the latest prototype js version. The latest today I think is 1.7.3

Comment: thx you John for answering.  I had updated to the latest prototype 1.7.2.  I'll go with that.